# How do I manually view an authenticated user's display name in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I know that you can set/retrieve an authenticated user's display name using Firebase but where is this being stored? Can I login to the Firebase console to see the display name?

Thank you!

Edit: Basically, the reason I need to be able to do all this is to prevent 2 users from having the same display name (username).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Where is the Firebase user's display name being stored ?

Well it's a good question because it's **hidden somewhere but it's not easily displayed**.

> Can I login to the Firebase console to see the display name ?

You can log in into the Firebase console **but you won't see the display name.**

> Prevent 2 users from having the same display name (username).

For this, one solution is to store somewhere in your Firebase realtime database all the usernames. (Like a specific node for usernames). And then either in code, you can check if it already exists or use database security rules to invalidate an already taken username. **But only with the display name info from Firebase authentification you can't prevent duplicates.**

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your last sentence- are you saying that the displayName property on Auth user can be a duplicate displayName with another user? I am testing this locally on my own Firebase project now and it seems like displayName duplicates are allowed.