# How to check my firebaseUser contains any displayName or not?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Neither (if firebaseUser.getDisplayName()!=null) this nor the below one is working for me:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser.getDisplayName() == null || firebaseUser.getDisplayName().trim().length() == 0){
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the `FirebaseUser` object contains a UID?

Comment: No, FirebaseUser contains the UID but do the UID contains the DisplayName is my concern

Comment: Might this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47409658/10182897) can you help

Comment: What do you mean if uid contains display name? I think you mean you want to check if the user object contains a display name.

Comment: Also do I understand correctly, you want to start an activity if the user has no display name?

Comment: Exactly I want to start an activity if the user has no display name

Comment: According to your requirement, your code segment should work. I suggest you also post the whole code of `SecondActivity`. Also, you said it is not working. How do you know it is not working. I mean what is happening when you run the app.

Comment: After updating my display name it still opening the MainActivity

Comment: Edit your question. Add whole code of SecondActivity

Comment: Sorry @VSSCHAITANYAChavali it was my fault in second Activity which I have decoded after 5 days, my answer is correct (forgive me considering a newbie)

Comment: @AmitGhosh Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> No, FirebaseUser contains the UID but do the UID contains the DisplayName is my concern

Yes, FirebaseUser object contains the UID, as well as the name. The `getDisplayName()` will always return the name, as well as the `getUid()` returns the UID. There is no way in which `getDisplayName()` can return the UID as it is not possible that the `getUid()` method to return the name.

Comment: Sorry Sir I'm new so I've made a mistake above my concern is do the user contain the display name and if it contains then how to start an activity based upon this

Comment: `if (firebaseUser.getDisplayName() != null || firebaseUser.getDisplayName().trim().length() != 0){` See the nagation `!=`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I think you mean `&&` otherwise an empty string will return true.

Comment: @VSSCHAITANYAChavali Ops, yes, that's right, the `&&` operator should be used.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for helping  it worked for me

Comment: You're very welcome, Amit.